# svn switch not working

Tags: svn

I have a working copy of code on my desktop that had a repo on `url_OLD`.

I had working copy of code on desktop which I imported to a new repo at `url_NEW`.  I can commit changes to that new repo.

When I try to set up repo on desktop (using xcode4) I get green lights on the directories but not on the repository bookmark (it stays yellow) and the hourglass just spins.  I've checked username and PW.

If I use commandline `svn co url_NEW`
 I get

```
svn: 'name' is already a working copy for a different URL
```

So I tried

```
svn switch --relocate url_OLD  url_NEW
```

I get

```
svn:  the repository at url_NEW has uuid of 'unique number' but WC has uuid of 'different number'
```

I'm lost.  Should I delete the repository to the `oldURL` within xcode organizer?  Are there other files/folders I should remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With switch command you change URL of repo for your Working Copy, **when**

- Repository have changed it's URL
- It is still **same old repo**

UUID is (as name suggest) unique identity of repo, URL-independent. If UUIDs are different, it means (for SVN) "They are different repos, not switchable"

If you want and have to use repo from NewURL, you have to dump it, replace UUID in  dump (with UUID of OldURL), kill repo, re-create it and load edited data. After these operations -switch to

Comment: So how do I delete the old repo?  Do I do that within Xcode organizer or do I have to use commandline?  Do you have sample?  I'm not concerned about reperving the old repo.  I have the code I have the code I want in the new repo.

Comment: I know nothing about XCode, but *if I really want delete repository*, I'll prefer remove it physically, by hand, from server. If you just want delete *references to old repo* - I think, organizer will be able  do it. If you have code, which you want to have in  repo, locally - as easiest way you can `svn co NewURL` in order to get new fresh WC, copy needed files to WC, `svn ci`... and forget about old WC and repo

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the repository was duplicated and not exported/imported using the svnadmin tools. This would cause the repository identifier (UUID) to be different. In this case, you'll have to delete and re-checkout the old repo in xcode.

Comment: OK.  How do I delete the old repo?  Can you give me some sample code? Thanks

Comment: I don't care about the old repo.  I just want to checkout the new repo but there appears to be some conflict between the two.